# iPhone: on button click Tab does not change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I am not able to change Tab on button click so what could be the problem?
Here is the code.
I have connected all outlets properly.

```
 -(IBAction) BackPressed :(id) sender  
{

 Calculator *calculator1 = [[Calculator alloc] initWithNibName:@"Calculator" bundle:nil];

 [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];

 [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:calculator1];}
```

please Help and Suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set viewcontrollers to tabbarcontroller initially. For example:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navFirst,navsecond, navthird, navfourth, navfifth,nil];
```

After that you can do the selectedIndex operation. Please check the questions and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406545/how-to-changed-the-selected-tab-items-in-the-tabbar-in-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're creating a new `Calculator` instance on your button click handler. What you probably want to do is change the tab on an existing view controller, and not to create a new one.

Comment: Yes I want to change the tab only. Calculator view controller is already there

Comment: Right. So what you want to do is call `setSelectedViewController:` on the instance that is already there, and NOT to create a new one.

Comment: However, it's weird that you'd click a button (a "back" button?) to change a tab - normally you'd simply click the tab you want to go to.